# Displaying HTML elements once the test cases is finished

Tags: javascript, angular5, karma-jasmine

How to remove the html elements that are displaying once the test cases are finished

Please find the below image

[image]

Comment: Change your test to remove the elements when it's finished.

Comment: @SLaks where do I have to configure to remove the elements when it's finished.

Comment: That completely depends on what your test does and how it adds the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you want to effectively 'hide' it, or actually delete it from the client's local code. Here's an example if just hiding it is fine:

```
document.getElementById('hideThisElement').style.display = 'none';
```

Otherwise you can actually delete it doing this:

```
document.getElementById('hideThisElement').remove();
```